# Shopware 6 : Scheduled Task does not working to update product data

Tags: cron, shopware, shopware6

I have created a scheduled task to synchronize meta data of product. But the meta data still not updating. FYI the state is 'Scheduled'

Task.php

```
namespace MetaGen\Service\ScheduledTask;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\MessageQueue\ScheduledTask\ScheduledTask;

class MetaGenTask extends ScheduledTask
{
    public static function getTaskName(): string
    {
        return 'metagen.meta_gen_task';
    }

    public static function getDefaultInterval(): int
    {
        return 10; // 10 sec
    }
}
```

HandlerTask.php

```
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Context;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepositoryInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\MessageQueue\ScheduledTask\ScheduledTaskHandler;

class MetaGenTaskHandler extends ScheduledTaskHandler
{
    protected EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository;
    public function __construct(EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    } 

    public static function getHandledMessages(): iterable
    {
        return [ MetaGenTask::class ];
    }

    public function run(): void
    {
        $this->productRepository->update([
            [
                'id' => 'a3d711095dd343608f5d0639c22dba48',
                'metaTitle' => 'Product test'
            ]
        ], Context::createDefaultContext());
    }
}
```

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

That probably means that there is currently no message consumer. Refer to the [docs](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/add-scheduled-task#executing-the-scheduled-task)

Try running

```
bin/console messenger:consume
```

After that your task should finally be executed.

Comment: I try to execute this command but it seems that other tasks are running, not the task I want to execute.

Comment: That command should run all tasks that are currently in flight